# Mobile browser shows wrong site

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, redirect, iis-8

I have a very weird issue going on.

I have a new website built with Asp.Net (previous site was possibly PHP on an Apache server). The site's web records all point to IP 1.2.3.4 for example:

When I type in

```
example.com
```

In a desktop browser it redirects to

```
https://example.com
```

Everything works as expected. The rewrite URL had been used on other sites so I know it's not the rewrite causing the following problem.

I clear my browser go into incognito on two different browsers and all works/shows the site as expected.

I now browse the same site on a mobile and it displays something completely different! When I say different I mean it shows the old site and the site was propagated over a week ago. I check the web records for both www and non www both point to the same IP address.

So I decided to ping the site externally and both show as the correct IP. I try a different mobile device and same problem.

I think if it was a IP/DNS problem then it would happen everywhere regardless of the device.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be going wrong here? I don't know what's causing the mobile devices to show the old website? If anyone needs more info feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below workarounds to resolve the issue:

1. Set the firewall inbound rule for the port number :

   Open "Windows Defender Firewall and Advanced Security" select "Inbound Rules" click "New Rule..." select "Port" then add TCP port 12345(your site port number) and click next to finish the process.
2. Recycle your site application pool.
3. Clear the browser cache.
4. Check your DNS setting
5. Use iis client cache setting:

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections pane, go to the site for which you want to disable caching.
- From the middle pane, select HTTP Response Headers.

  [image]
- In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane.
- In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane.

  [image]

Retsart your iis server.